# $(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$ - possible value pairs

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

We introduced the complex numbers as elements of $ \mathrm{Mat}(2\times 2, \mathbb{R})$ with

$$
\mathbb{C} \ni x =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b \\
b & a \\
\end{array}\right) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} & \frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} & \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then we concluded that $0 \leq \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \leq 1$ and therefore we could find an $\alpha$ so that $\cos \alpha = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\sin \alpha = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. Then we can write the matrix with $\cos$ and $\sin$ and can write it as the Euler form as well. So far so good.

My question ist about the following:

Why is it that we cand find an $\alpha$ so that $\cos \alpha = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\sin \alpha = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ **for every possible value combination of $a$ and $b$**?
Can't be there a combination of $a$ and $b$ where we can't find one and the same angle $\alpha$ so that the identites are true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two key factors here: one is the one noted, that each of these quantities is between $0$ and $1$.

But the other, which is *very* important, is that the sum of their squares is equal to $1$:
$$\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2 = 1.$$
Because the sum of their squares is equal to $1$, the point 
$$\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$
satisfies the equation
$$x^2+y^2=1.$$
But this is the equation of the circle of radius $1$ with center at the origin. *Every* point on that circle is of the form $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the line that goes from the origin to the point. So that means that $\alpha$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Find an $\alpha$ so that $\cos(\alpha)=  \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. This is possible because the fraction is between $-1$ and $1$.

Then note that

$$\sin^2(\alpha)= 1- \cos^2(\alpha)=1- \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2} \,.$$

Thus either $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ or  $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

In the first situation you are done, while if $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ then

$$\cos(-\alpha)=  \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \,;\,  \sin(-\alpha)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could simply plot the point $(a,b)$ in the $x$-$y$ plane and let $\alpha$ be the angle formed by the positive $x$-axis and the ray joining the origin with $(a,b)$ (measured counterclockwise starting from the positive $x$-axis to the ray).

Then the distance from $(a,b)$ to the origin is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\cos\alpha ={a\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\sin\alpha ={b\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, essentially by definition. (Use similar triangles and the unit circle definition of the trigonometric functions if you like.)